# centos tomcat startup page not coming

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos

I am facing issue in accessing the home page after starting up tomcat in CentOs.
I have installed JDK 7 and tomcat 7.
Following is the output when I startup the tomcat.

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java
>
> Using CLASSPATH:
>   /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Tomcat started.

But when I try accessing the home page at http://:8080 , I am not getting the home screen in my browser.
I crosschecked the same by following command.

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

It results in following output:

```
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Please note, I am trying to access the home page from a different machine than the one in which tomcat is running.

Comment: Are you trying to access the server through _http://:8080_? That is not a valid URL. If it is not a typo in the question, try _http://localhost:8080_.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I am using http://machineip:8080. I am trying to access the page from some other machine, so I am giving the ip instead of localhost.

Comment: are you able to access the home page from same machine? http://localhost:8080